# How to use an aggregate function on an array column in cosmos-db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos item like :-

```
{
  "id": "123,
  "meta": "ancdkjlerlh"
  "reason": [
        "reason1",
        "reason2"
    ],
  "status": "REJECTED"
}
```

I need to find the count of items for each reason.

I tried something like this :-

```sql
SELECT count(1) as CountOfRejected, 
c.reason
FROM c
WHERE c.status= "REJECTED"
GROUP BY c.reason
```

which treats the entire reason array as a whole.
The [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by) method requires a second parameter to use in GROUP BY clause which I think will take 1 reason at a time. Is there a way to do it in a single query like in SQL?
I want result in this format

```
         Reason | CountOfRejected |
        --------------------------
        Reason 1 | 10
        Reason 2 | 5
        Reason 3 | 7
```

Comment: If you only want to get the count of items for each reason, you can use ARRAY_LENGTH() function. Try this SQL:`SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(c.reason) AS CountOfRejected FROM c WHERE c.status= "REJECTED"`

Comment: I want the count of each reason eg: 
Reason 1  5 , reason2 -11 , reason3 -20

Comment: I see. Does this achieve your requirement? `SELECT COUNT(r) as CountOfRejected,r as Reason FROM c JOIN r IN c.reason WHERE c.status= "REJECTED" GROUP BY r`

Comment: @SteveZhao Thanks a lot .This works like a charm! They still don't allow order by on the result though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by

Comment: Yes, Group by can't be used with Order By in Cosmos DB by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(r) as CountOfRejected,r as Reason 
FROM c JOIN r IN c.reason 
WHERE c.status= "REJECTED" 
GROUP BY r
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "CountOfRejected": 1,
        "Reason": "reason3"
    },
    {
        "CountOfRejected": 1,
        "Reason": "reason2"
    },
    {
        "CountOfRejected": 2,
        "Reason": "reason1"
    }
]
```